# Turning a sum of an array into a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, sum, equation

```
for (i = 0; i < ArrayName.length; i++){
```

Is there anyway to turn this equation output into a variable, i've tried multiple options but can't seem to get it. The array is different numbers that a user can enter via prompts and I need to get the sum of the user inputs and add it together then show it on the document.

Comment: Which equation output are you talking about?

Comment: It seems you are letting stackoverflow do your homework. Please google some javascript tutorials to help you find these simple answers yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by doing the following:

```
// This will hold the sum
let variable = 0; // Declare this variable outside your loop
```

Now loop through the array and add the current value to the variable like so:

```
variable += arrayName[i];
```

Hopefully this helps your problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum;
for (i = 0; i < ArrayName.length; i++){
sum=sum+ArrayName[i];
}
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function like this:

```js
let array = [5, 25, 15, 10, 50]

let sum = array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr)

console.log(sum)
```